# Why can't write in Android Studio (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I installed flutter in Android, but there is a problem showing a black mark preventing me from writing or deleting.As image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0maHc.png)

It only appears if you choose to build a flutter app.Do not come if I choose Java android.

Also if you click on the insert button in my keyboard it will disappear, but if I move to a different page, it will come back.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Press **0** from **Numpad** which is usually the right side of the keyboard (*Not from the **Alphanumeric** section*).